# Hiding sub menu with delay in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu with sub menu. When you click on menu item, sub menu will be visible. When mouse leave the menu, sub menu will be hidden after 1 sec. What I want is that if mouse back to menu before 1 sec hiding function terminate.

Here is what I did:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CPxTA/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item</span></li>
    <li><span>Item</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Item2</span></li>
            <li><span>Item2</span></li>
            <li><span>Item2</span></li>
            <li><span>Item2</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Item</span></li>
    <li><span>Item</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Item3</span></li>
            <li><span>Item3</span></li>
            <li><span>Item3</span></li>
            <li><span>Item3</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body,htnl,ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
    background:#ddd;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    padding:3px 10px;
    margin:4px;
    background:#bbb;
}

ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").show();
}).parent().mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("ul li").find("ul").hide();
    },1000);
}).parent().mouseenter(function(){
    $("ul li").stop(true,true);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have some reference to timeout which you can later use to cancel:

```
var timeout;
$("ul li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").show();
}).parent().mouseout(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $("ul li").find("ul").hide();
    },1000);
}).mouseover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout)
});
```

**EDIT:** mouseover/out instead of mouseenter/leave and also added `clearTimeout` in mouseout (helps with multiple clicks within 1000ms)

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MnL6m/

Comment: Yeah, try removing parent() from just before mouseenter

Comment: lol, jQuery have native method for this purpose [`$.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: and how do you cancel? the page you linked to says it can not be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the timeout to a variable and use clearTimeout.

```
var timeout;

$("ul li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").show();
}).parent().mouseleave(function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $("ul li").find("ul").hide();
    },1000);
}).parent().mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $("ul li").stop(true,true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

`$("li ul").hide();`

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    $("li ul").hide();//added here
    $(this).find("ul").show();
}).parent().mouseleave(function(){......
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/CPxTA/1/)